# Jest encountered an unexpected token - import (Angular CLI 6)

Tags: angular, jestjs

On Mac, I am having problem getting jest installed and working in an angular/cli (v6) app. Regardless of the methods I used to place jest (listed below), I am getting error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /Users/owner/Code/testjest/src/setup-jest.ts:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import 'jest-preset-angular';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
```

The methods I tried included:

- `ng g @briebug/jest-schematic:add` (https://github.com/briebug/jest-schematic)
- https://brianflove.com/2018/05/26/angular-jest-testing/
- https://www.lambda-it.ch/blog/post/using-jest-with-angular
- https://blog.angularindepth.com/integrate-jest-into-an-angular-application-and-library-163b01d977ce

OTOH, when I cloned https://github.com/blove/ngrx-testing/tree/master, the repo runs jest just fine - which, I think, excludes problem with my jest package installed globally

The following SO answers did not help:

- [Jest encountered an unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994111/jest-encountered-an-unexpected-token)
- [Jest - Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721091/jest-unexpected-token-import)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today I found same error message then this is my solution.

- clear jest caching by `jest --clearCache`
- add `"module": "commonjs"`in tsconfig.spec.json

ref: https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/194

Comment: Yep, I confirm, module resolution came to the rescue. I found the solution the other day, but forgot to update it here. Accepting your answer.